# Testing App on my own iPhone without developer program. XCode 4.2 and IOS 5.0 SDK

Tags: ios, testing, xcode4.2, jailbreak

I've tried many tutorials to try my app on my jailbroken device and none of them have worked out.
I am in Xcode 4.2, IOS 5.0 SDK and iPhone 5.1.1

Has anyone archived this with this settings running an app?

Comment: why is this down voted? this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the easiest way to test apps without a developer account is by using [JailCoder](http://jailcoder.com/)

Comment: JailCoder website is no longer available :(

Answer (score 0):

**Good news!**
Apple will release next version Xcode 7 will eliminate restriction of developer program log in to test apps on IOS device. I successfully did below.

For now Xcode 7 beta : https://developer.apple.com/xcode/